# Rest assured receiving null for actual value but Postman shows value exists

Tags: java, postman, rest-assured

I am automating a google places api using rest assured (java) and I am having issues with my results which I don't seem to understand.

So basically when I use postman to perform a GET request for the following URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=AIzaSyDWz5aGXygtrt3hsn99yXv_oocw09PSOH
```

It outputs the results as so:

```
    "html_attributions": [],
    "results": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": -33.8585858,
                    "lng": 151.2100415
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": -33.85723597010728,
                        "lng": 151.2113913298927
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": -33.85993562989272,
                        "lng": 151.2086916701072
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png",
            "id": "8e980ad0c819c33cdb1cea31e72d654ca61a7065",
            "name": "Cruise Bar, Restaurant & Events",
            "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": true,
                "weekday_text": []
            },

... //more json
}
```

However when I use rest assured to check the response of this request, it syas there is an error in my assertion. It states:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path results[0].geometry.viewport.northeast.lat doesn't match.
Expected: -33.85723597010728
  Actual: null
```

I am unsure why the 'Actual' is displaying null as postman shows there's a response and it seems like my code is correct and is checking the correct place for the response:

```
package rest.basic.testing;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.when;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

public class GetRequestSample {

    //Full URL

    /*https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362
     &radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=AIzaSyDWz5aGXygtrt3hsn99yXv_oocw09PSOHE */

    //BaseURI
    static String baseURI = "https://maps.googleapis.com";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        searchPlaceInGoogle();
    }

    public static void searchPlaceInGoogle() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = baseURI;

        //In the given() we put the parameters which you can see by matching the below with the full URL displayed above

        given()
        .param("location", "33.8670522,151.1957362")
        .param("radius", "1500")
        .param("type", "restaurant")
        .param("key", "AIzaSyDWz5aGXygtrt3hsn99yXv_oocw09PSOHE");
       //In the when we place in our resources which is after the url and before the ?      
        //In the then is our assertions
        when()
        .get("maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json")        
        .then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and()
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON).and()
        .body("results[0].geometry.viewport.northeast.lat", equalTo("-33.85723597010728"));

        //To prove the code above is running successfully
        System.out.println("Request is executed successful");
    }


}
```

Can anybody see why the actual result is showing null?

Comment: I'm more familiar with other test harnesses, but I would generally expect the JSON path to start with `$.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logging feature from REST assured in case of failure to check yourself what was indeed in the response body or not:
[log if validation fails](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#log-if-validation-fails%20log-if-validation-fails)

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you do equality comparisons on latitude or longitude, it will never pass as the underlying values keeps on changing every time.

Using `containString` gets around that problem and should work for you:

```
.body("results[0].geometry.viewport.northeast.lat", containString("-33.85723597010728"));
```